# Question about complete DVR.

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

Is there a simple proof that you know to the following statement:

> If the residue field $k$ of a complete DVR $R$ has the same characteristic as $R$, then $R$ contains a subfield isomorphic to $k$.

This is not homework, and the book I am reading is an old book, so I was wondering if someone knew a more recent proof (The proof presented in the book is for characteristic 0).

Comment: The statement is true for any complete Noetherian local ring $R$, DVR or not -- and the fact is one of the lynchpins in the proof of Cohen's Structure Theorems (1946).

Comment: You're welcome, @Luis.  And by the way, I doubt that there is a simple proof, even for the case where the complete ring $R$ is a DVR.  However (and you probably know this), the fact that $R$ contains a field isomorphic to a *subfield* of $k$ has a simple proof, even if $R$ is not complete, as long as $R$ is local and has the same characteristic as $k$.

Comment: @neilme Why can't you just take the prime subfield? :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis, your prime subfield does not necesssarily have to be isomorphic to your residue field ($\mathbb{Z}_p)$

Comment: @Luis He just said that $R$ contains a field isomorphic to a subfield of $k$.

Comment: I think we might be misunderstanding each other. The $p-adics$ have characteristic 0 and hence their prime subfield is $\mathbb{Q}$. Their residue field is isomorphic to $GF(p)$. $\mathbb{Q}$ is not isomorphic to a subfield of $GF(p)$.  This is what I mean, since the characteristic changes. You might mean a different thing.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Yes, if the characteristic does not change, you are right. I thought you meant in general, sorry.

Comment: @neilme the proof for the case where char(k) is zero for a complete DVR uses Zorn's lemma and Hensel's lemma. It's fairly elementary. For char(p) the book skips the proof. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Luis Yes, I know that proof.  It's the same for any complete char 0 Noetherian local ring.  But I don't consider Hensel's lemma itself to be elementary.  Actually, if you want to know in characteristic $p$ what you do (if $k$ is perfect) is you take the intersection of all the subrings $R^{p^e}$ of $R$ (over all positive integers $e$), and then you show that this is a field and isomorphic to $k$ via the natural map.  The proof uses Hensel's lemma, Zorn's lemma, and Krull's intersection theorem.  If $k$ is not perfect, you need to talk about ``$p$-bases'', which is definitely not elementary.

Comment: A good source to read about this is http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W10/supStructure.pdf.

Comment: Thanks again. Really helpful.